# Extracting energy from curvature

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

**The device**

Imagine i connect 4 rigid rods of equal length together in
a square. This thing has 4 corners, each with a 90° angle. Going
around the whole thing i make one full rotation, so 360°.

Now i replace one of the rods with something else:
In case A i just replace it with a stiff spring. That
spring is build so that its uncompressed length is the
same as the rod it replaces. The new object now has
3 rigid rods at 90° angles, and one spring, with zero
potential energy stored in the spring

In case B i replace one of the rods with some kind of
linear actuator attached to a generator. Changing the
length of that actuator will turn the generator and
generate extractable electrical energy.

The rods are as rigid as physical possible, so their
internal forces are still mediated by the electromagnetic
force.

**The setup**

This device is build far away from a gravitational field
in freefall. Now i bring this device closer to a planet
(with ordinary schwarzschild geometry). The closer i get
the more geometry is distorted. In particular, as the
device encloses a finite area, if i parallel transport
a vector around it, it does not close back to the 360°,
but has some angular deficit. This in turn will in case
A compress the spring and in case B compress the actuator
which will generate energy in the generator. In case A
there is some energy in the spring, in case B i can
in principle extract that energy and store it in a capacitor.
By varying the load on the generator i can extract as much
energy as i want, up to the point where the material strength
cannot withstand the force anymore.

(since the device is not a single point a "local observer"
is not well defined, but i assume an observer very close
to the device)

**Extended setup 1**

I can place this thing in an elliptical orbit around a black
hole, so it oscillates between regions of high curvature
and regions of low curvature. During every cycle the actuator
is extended and compressed, generating energy every time.

**Extended setup 2**

I can stand on a planet with no atmosphere and launch this device
on a suborbital trajectory. I am expending energy to do this
but in principle, the energy extracted by the generator can
exceed the energy expended to launch it in the first place.
I can also in principle recover the kinetic energy leaving
me with a net positive energy.

**Question 1**

Where does this energy come from (if it even works)? Would observers agree that
the actuator is moving? (for device B)

**Queston 2**

Since the changing curvature creates material stress which
in turn applies a force on the spring (for device A), does
the whole device "resists" moving? Or is there no counterforce
on the device itself?

Comment: In the classical version, this would just be a device for extracting energy from tidal forces. Which obviously works, as Io demonstrates. Energy is taken from the orbit in such a way that it circularises; in a sense this is "resisting" the elliptical motion.

Comment: Not sure about setup 2. To get useful net energy, you need a substantial machine, which involves substantial energy t get into orbit. As a practical example, is the energy expended by astronauts keeping fit on the ISS in anyway comparable to the energy involved in getting them there? That might be one benchmark of a possible return  on such a system.

Comment: @User171879 It does not need to get into orbit, any trajectory with changing  r changes the curvature. The device generates the energy during the flight, and when i catch it (for example electromagnetically) i can recover the kinetic energy, giving me the same kinetic energy back i launched it with in the first place

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/464526/40394)